# Jasmine throws error after all tests passes

Tags: angular, jasmine

**All of my unit tests are passing**. But there is error thrown like:

```
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. thrown
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 20 of 79 (skipped 4) ERROR (0 secs / 3.634 secs)
Chrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
```

It is not because of my implementation. **I am not using any afterAll intialization block in my tests**. Any ideas?

Comment: You are probably spying on services and not returning value properly, somewhere where you have observable

Comment: can you add your test?

Comment: The problem is that all test are passing, output in console does not suggest which test is causing this. It is all I've got. I don't have any afterrAll method in my tests. Any ideas?

Comment: `An error was thrown in afterAll` tell you something? Probably you should start looking there.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: [Angular Tests break at random: "Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942622/angular-tests-break-at-random-uncaught-typeerror-you-provided-undefined-whe)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this type of problem before.
This came either from an asynchronous test which should not have been, or from a cleaning to be done in the afterall (unsubscribe subscriptions or TestBed.resetTestingModule()).